# How can i multiply 2 curl outputs together

Tags: bash, curl, awk

I have the outputs of 2 APIs with this Bash Json Parser

```
curl 'APIxyz' | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' |\
  awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' |\
  grep -w "total_hash" | cut -c14-100
```

After using cut I have the correct numbers (like 15.25), but how can I use 2 times curl and multiply it together, would prefer using not an extra SH script, is this even possible in bash? And if how?

Comment: Add exact output of your pipe and your desired output to your question.

Comment: In `sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g'` the `''` is doing absolutely nothing and in `awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}'` you aren't using the variable `k` at all, and you're using split() with an array completely unnecessarily vs just setting FS, and what's the point of that loop if you only want 1 number output, and you don't need grep+sed+cut when you're already using awk. So - your existing script has some issues you might want to post a new question to ask for help with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the results of the two `curl` commands in variables,
and then multiply them:

```
v1=$(curl ...)
v2=$(curl ...)

bc <<< "$v1 * $v2"
```

You could write in one line if you really really really need:

```
bc <<< "$(curl ...) * $(curl ...)"
```

Comment: ty for the help, but is it possible using only one line?

Comment: @FlorianStröger why do you want it on one line? Do you mean using only one `curl` instead of two?

Comment: i want to use them in my conky config, and i would like to prefer not use another file than the .conkyrc

Comment: and i tested it with 31.2559 * 17.0796 and it only outputs that .2559 isnt an arithmetical operator

Comment: @FlorianStröger indeed, Bash is not so good with floating point math. See my updated answer. I also added a solution written on a single line.